# C# Core 1.1 Web API Receive zip file

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman, .net-core-1.1

I created Web API endpoint to receive a zip file which looks like this

```
    [HttpPut()]
    [Consumes("application/zip")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ImportZip()
    {
        var zipFile = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault();
        ....
```

And I'm trying to test it via Postman with such request:
[image]
[image]

But I'm getting exception "System.InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type: application/zip"

What I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks!

**EDIT**
Request actually passes through [Consumes("application/zip")] attribute, but crashing on "HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault();"

**EDIT2**
Ok, so finally I successfully received a file when I didn't put any header in the request and removed [Consumes("application/zip")] attribute. In `Request.Form.Files` my file have a type "application/x-zip-compressed" but when I'm trying to use it in headers content-type and in Consumes attribute I get same crash `System.InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed`

Comment: I'm pretty shure the content type `application/zip` is unknown to your asp.net core application. I think you must upload your zip as `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: @NtFreX - System.InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Comment: I think you also need to set the body type in postman to `binary`.

Comment: @NtFreX - same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IFormFile` to transfer your zip. Your WebApi endpoint must be updated to this:

```
 [HttpPut]
 [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
 public void Put(IFormFile file)
 {
    var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
 }
```

Postman request should look something like this (You don't need `Content-Type` header as it gets resolved on request):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Oluwafemi!  It's working actually, and with this approach I can read a file from request like I did before (`HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault();`). But as I understand - all files in request will be read and I want to have restriction only for zip

Answer (score 2):

Postman will send `multipart/form-data` as `Content-Type`. Normaly you only specify the `Consumes` attribute when the web api action has to support multiple content types or when you wan't to support a specific content type.

As your web api action depends on `HttpContext.Request.Form.Files` the `Content-Type` has to be `multipart/form-data` anyway.

The best option to only allow zip files is to try parsing it. If it fails you know a wrong file has been uploaded.

```
[HttpPut("api/import")]
public IActionResult ImportZip()
{
    var file = Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault();
    if (file == null)
        return BadRequest();

    try
    {
        using (var zip = new ZipArchive(file.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            // do stuff with the zip file
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Another option would be to check the [BOM (Byte order mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) of the file.